# Geodesic on a Hilbert manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, hilbert-spaces, geodesic

Given a Hilbert manifold $\mathcal H$ (always using the natural Hilbert inner product) and a geodesic $\Gamma(t)$ in this manifold, can one show that the projection of this geodesic onto a submanifold $\mathcal S$ of $\mathcal H$ (corresponding Hilbert subspace) is necessarily also a geodesic in $\mathcal S$? Or show a counterexample?
If this is not a valid conclusion, could it be valid under some restriction?

Let me know if I have made any incorrect assumptions or the problem needs further specification.

Comment: How do you define the projection of a geodesic? Take a finite-dimensional example: the manifold $\mathbb H$ is a sphere $S^2$, the submanifold $\mathcal S$ is the equator, and the geodesic is an arc of a great circle passing through the North Pole. How would you project this geodesic onto the equator?